# How to generate an IOS IPA in windows using Android studio for a Flutter app?

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I am new to this flutter based app creation. Now I successfully created one sample app in my windows system android studio with flutter plugin that app also running successful. OK, now I want to generate the IPA app for the same application. I don't know how to generate the IPA for IOS device in using android studio? anyone help me please..

I am using windows 10 system and my android studio version as 3.4.2

I want to generate .ipa file in android studio, like how i generate .apk file in android studio.

Comment: I thought you needed a Mac to develop in iOS

Comment: Using Android studio we can generate only apk file, if you want to generate ipa file you need mac machine, using windows you cannot generate ipa file

Answer (score 9):

The only way to generate an IPA from you windows machine is by using a CI/CD service like [`Codemagic`](https://codemagic.io/start/) using the steps described in this [article](https://medium.com/flutter-community/developing-and-debugging-flutter-apps-for-ios-without-a-mac-8d362a8ec667):

1. link your repository ([`Github`](https://github.com), [`BitBucket`](https://bitbucket.org/) , or [`Gitlab`](https://gitlab.com)).
2. from settings > build for platforms > IOS
3. change the `.app` file you received to `.zip` and extract it.
4. You will find a file called `Runner.app`, put in a folder and compress it back.
5. change the extension from `.zip` to `.ipa`.

And here's your first IOS build without a Mac device.

Comment: Mazin Ibrahim thanks for your guide. But Any other possibilities to generate .ipa without any paid tools?

Comment: It has a free plan, which you can use to generate the .ipa