# How can I find XCODE_WORKSPACE name and SCHEME name

Tags: ios, xcode, codemagic

I have created an application Test1 in Android Studio (Windows 10) and I would like to convert it for IOS (.ipa). I have read the article:
[How to generate an IOS IPA in windows using Android studio for a Flutter app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57721700/how-to-generate-an-ios-ipa-in-windows-using-android-studio-for-a-flutter-app)
and I 'm using codemagic for this project.
In the 2nd Step (from settings > build for platforms > IOS) I faced the error `xcodebuild build -workspace "$XCODE_WORKSPACE.xcworkspace" -scheme "$XCODE_SCHEM ..`

The configuration file I used is codemagic.yaml

```
# Check out https://docs.codemagic.io/getting-started/building-a-native-ios-app/ for more information
# Please review and update values in curly braces

workflows:
    ios-app:
        name: iOS App
        environment:
            vars:
                XCODE_WORKSPACE: "{{ ADD WORKSPACE NAME HERE }}"
                XCODE_SCHEME: "{{ ADD SCHEME NAME HERE }}"
            xcode: latest
            cocoapods: default
        scripts:
            - xcodebuild build -workspace "$XCODE_WORKSPACE.xcworkspace" -scheme "$XCODE_SCHEME" CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="" CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED=NO
        artifacts:
            - $HOME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/**/Build/**/*.app
            - $HOME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/**/Build/**/*.dSYM
```

I suppose that the problem is in the environment variables (XCODE_WORKSPACE, XCODE_SCHEME).
How can I find the names of the variables?

App's name is Test1 (not the real name). I published on github with URL (https://github.com/Psiloritis/Test1)

Layout name is "activity_main.xml"
Java name is "MainActivity.java"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All these variables (`XCODE_WORKSPACE`, `XCODE_PROJECT`, `XCODE_SCHEME`) correspond to file names in your iOS project, the default values for Flutter projects are `Runner.xcworkspace`, `Runner.xcodeproj`, and `Runner` respectively.

The easiest way to build a Flutter app for iOS is by using the UI settings in Codemagic, but if you prefer using yaml, it will be easier to set up everything in the UI and then export the configuration as codemagic.yaml.

You can connect to the Codemagic build machine using the VNC connection if you want to modify configuration files through Xcode, see the guide [here](https://blog.codemagic.io/remote-access-to-virtual-mac-build-machine/). Also, check out [this guide](https://blog.codemagic.io/app-store-connect-api-codemagic-cli-tools/) about setting up automatic iOS code signing in Codemagic.

For a general overview of iOS code signing, you can visit [ioscodesigning.io](https://ioscodesigning.io/).

Comment: Thanks, I' ll try it!